# How to deal with concurrency on core data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, concurrency

I've been wandering around google, stackoverflow  and internet trying to understand how to work with core data and deal with the concurrency.

Consider that we have 2 tables, Events and Rooms. 
An Event can have 1+ Rooms.

FunctionA - AddEvent

FunctionB - AddRoom

FunctionC - SearchRoom -> returns RoomEntity or nil

My problem, I keep getting these errors

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "Could not merge changes." UserInfo={conflictList=(
    "NSMergeConflict (0x10a507160) for NSManagedObject (0x1092f00c0) with objectID '0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://A34C65BD-F9F0-4CCC-A9FB-1B1F5E48C70E/Rooms/p1>' with oldVersion = 116 and newVersion = 124 and old object snapshot = {\n    location = Lisboa;\n    name = \"\\U00cdndico LX\";\n} and new cached row = {\n    location = Lisboa;\n    name = \"\\U00cdndico LX\";\n}"
```

Notice the information of the Rooms is equal

my approach is the following.

1- I call the webservice once ( it brings a json with data of 3 types of Events ) These 3 all have the same json structure and share the same managedObjectContext passed by parameter

2- I create a managedObject

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
managedObjectContext.parent?.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType
```

3-

```
 managedObjectContext.perform(
        {
            do
            {

                try self.deleteAllEventsFromDb()

                FunctionA(eventList, managedObjectContext) -> save
                FunctionA(eventList2, managedObjectContext) -> save
                FunctionA(eventList3, managedObjectContext) -> save

                self.DatabaseDispatchGroup.enter()
                try managedObjectContext.save()
                self.DatabaseDispatchGroup.leave()
                completion(Result.Success(true))
            } 
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                completion(Result.Success(false))
            }
      })
```

4- For each Event I execute the same FunctionA to create and save the data in database (managedObjectContext.insert(eventEntity)) . This will work over several tables but lets only consider Events and Rooms(FunctionB).

5- FunctionA contains functionB. Function B search for an existing Room(FunctionC->returns entity?) if it doesn't exists(nil), it creates the entity ( should I save here? )

6- If a Room exists, gets the entity and tries to update the data

Not sure if its making any difference but when I save I do these saves I do it between a dispatchGroup

```
DatabaseDispatchGroup.enter()
try managedObjectContext.save()
DatabaseDispatchGroup.leave()
```

I was using a static managedObjectContext which was used for all the database requests but now I decided to create a objectContext per function which accesses the database.

I do keep the same persistentContainer and the same DispatchGroup for all requests

```
private override init() {
persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")

        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores() { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
            }

        }
}
```

It seems to me that my problem is that I am Storing the changes in memory, and always doing updates over the initial data meaning that when I execute save() the context the data is not updated for the next operation?

How/when am I suppose to execute the save function?

Thank you

Comment: you can use parent child pattern for concurrency in core data http://developmentnow.com/2015/04/28/experimenting-with-the-parent-child-concurrency-pattern-to-optimize-coredata-apps/

Comment: My first approach was using a static MOC, but it wasn't working, I still had concurrency problems. I think it was because I was mixing DispatchGroup with .perform ( I thought they had the same objective ). So if I use a static MOC with .perform it should work right?

Answer (score 0):

Once context is being saved, global notification is being posted: ContextDidSave notification.

When using multiple contexts (and not using parent-child approach) you should use this notification and either:

- Re-fetch/refresh data in case you need to update view or perform some operation on new data set (using either fetch request or refreshObjects: API).
- Merge changes to other contexts (remember about thread confinement! do that only on proper context queues). [(merge doc)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506606-mergechanges)

There are many articles about it, check for instance [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/174082/multiple-managed-object-contexts-with-core-data-tutorial)
and [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext)

Comment: i had the idea that dispatchGroup was used to prevent multiple requests simultaneously. :P i was wrong